# http API request Angular 12 is empty on the HTML page

Tags: angular, api

I'm a little bit confused while trying to make a call to an API.
I first created a service that is calling the API:

```
public getCategories(): Observable<any> {
  let getCategoriesUrl = 'http://localhost:4300/WS/GetCategories';
  return this.http.get<any>(getCategoriesUrl, {
    headers: this.httpOptions, responseType: 'text' as 'json'
  });
}
```

In my component I have a method that retrieves the data. My data is not clean that's why do clean special caracters that are returned. That's also why in my service i do not retrieve an observable of a specific model but of 'any'. Here is the implementation.

```
private getCategories() {
  this.soapService.getCategories().subscribe(
    (res) => {
      console.log(typeof res);
      res = res.replace(/\n/g, '');
      this.replacement.forEach(
        item => {
          res = res.replace(item, '');
        }
      );
      // res is a string with all data from API call => parsing string to object
      // console.log(res);
      this.categoriesResponseModel = JSON.parse(res);
      console.log('iterate after string parsing');
      // @ts-ignore
      for (const category of this.categoriesResponseModel.CATEGORIES) {
        // console.log(category);
        this.categories.push(category);
      }
      console.log("In get categories");
      console.log("Output  ", this.categories);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    },
    () => {
      console.log('Completed - Categories pushed');
    }
  );
}
```

In the method output is printed with the expected values on the line containing the following console.log:  `console.log("Output  ", this.categories);`

[image]

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('# ngOnInit() called');
  this.getCategories();
  console.log(this.categories)
  console.log("output  " + this.categories)
}
```

In the ngOnInit i do have an empty array as output. I test to display the result in the HTML page:

```
{{ categories.length }}
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
  {{ category.CategoryID }} - {{ category.CategoryName }}: {{ category.DocDescription }}
</div>
```

I obtain length equals to 0 unfortunatelly.

Comment: console.log in ngOnInit does not work and should not work since this is an async call. However, {{ categories.length }} should be non-zero. How many times is this line being called ... this.categories.push(category); ... ? this is the most important code ... Also where do you define this.categories as an empty array?

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. In this.categorie.push(category) I have 3 entries in my getCategories method. That's confusing me. I don't think it's related but the component is lazy loaded...

Comment: lazy loading wont effect anything - is push called 3 times? - where do you define this.categories?

Comment: I define the this member in the component. Simply declaring it this way: categories: CategoryModel[] = [];

Comment: ok fine, as expected, so how many times is push called? push adds an item to an array so if you call it 3 times there should be 3 times in the array - hence how many times is it called?

Comment: Indeed ...  it is called 3 times as I have 3 entries. I update the question with a capture...

Comment: console.log("Output  ", this.categories, this.categories.length); ..... length here is 3? ..................................................... {{ categories.length }} ... length here is 0?

Comment: In HTML : {{ categories.length }} i obtain 0 ... In console.log I have 3 entries.

Comment: this is weird! is your code on github or somewhere I can see it?

Comment: That's because change detection needs the array to be recreated, you should not push into it and expect the items to get rendered (unless you inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `cd.detectChanges()` after pushing all the categories in).

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu !! Thanks... I injected the ChangeDetectorRef and I called instead the markForCheck once the values are pushed onto the array :). I'll post the updated code !!

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('# ngOnInit() called');
  this.getCategories();
  console.log(this.categories)
  console.log("output  " + this.categories)
}
```

Here `console.log(this.categories)` might be `undefined` due to async assignment inside the subscription. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921) canonical post on async data.

2. Pushing to an array doesn't trigger Angular change detection. In this case, you could directly assign to the variable.

```js
this.categories = this.categoriesResponseModel.CATEGORIES;
```

instead of

```
  // console.log(category);
  this.categories.push(category);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
// @ts-ignore
for (const category of this.categoriesResponseModel.CATEGORIES) {
  // console.log(category);
  this.categories.push(category);
}
```

you should try this:

```
this.categories = [...this.categoriesResponseModel.CATEGORIES];
```

Comment: thanks ! i'm going to implement this. I always forget the spread operator.

Answer (score 0):

I've been inspired by Octavian Mărculescu proposal to use ChangeDetectorRef.
Here is my updated code for getCategories in the component.

I also changed the place i call the getCategories and placed it in the constructor

```
constructor(@Inject(TRANSLATION) public readonly lang: Translation,
            private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
            private soapService: SoapApiService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.getCategories();
}
```

Here is the implementation:

```
getCategories(): void {
  const values: CategoryModel[] = [];
  const response = this.soapService.getCategories().subscribe(
    (res) => {
      console.log(typeof res);
      res = res.replace(/\n/g, '');
      this.replacement.forEach(
        item => {
          res = res.replace(item, '');
        }
      );
      // res is a string with all data from API call => parsing string to object
      // console.log(res);
      this.categoriesResponseModel = JSON.parse(res);
      console.log('iterate after string parsing');
      // @ts-ignore
      for (const category of this.categoriesResponseModel.CATEGORIES) {
        // console.log(category);
        values.push(category);
      }
      this.cd.markForCheck();
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    },
    () => {
      console.log('Completed - Categories pushed');
      this.categories = values;
      console.log(this.categories);
    }
  );
}
```